# Pagination for Dropdownlist filter data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My default start page has no data

Then filter out the data in the database after the two  drop-down list
I hope that the filtered data can be displayed in pagination if there are more than ten records.

But I don't know how to do.
I'm new in this.

Here is my javascript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#CITY").change(function () { ChangeCity(); });
        $("#AREA").change(function () { ChangeArea(); });
        $(document).on('submit', '#ButtonSubmit', function () {
            return false;
        });


    })
    function SetareaEmpty() {
        $('#CITY').empty();
        $('#CITY').append($('<option></option>').val('').text('select'));
    }
    function ChangeCity() {
        var selectedCity = $.trim($('#CITY option:selected').val());
        if ($.trim(selectedCity.length) > 0) {
            ChangeArea(selectedCity);
        }
        else {
            SetareaEmpty()
        }
    }
    function ChangeArea(selectedCity) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSecondDDL", "Getarea")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { cityName: selectedCity },
            success: function (mems) {
                if (mems.length > 0) {
                    $('#AREA').empty();
                    $('#AREA').append($('<option></option>').val('').text('select'));
                }
                $.each(mems, function (i, member) {
                    $("#AREA").append($('<option></option>').val(member).text(member));

                });
            }
        });

    }
    function SerchallData(selectedCity) {
        var selectedCity = $('#CITY option:selected').val();
        var selectedValue = $('#AREA option:selected').val();
        if ($.trim(selectedValue).length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Getmap", "Getarea")',
                data: { cityName: selectedCity, areaName: selectedValue },
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#Mytable>tbody').empty();
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var row = $('<tr><td>'>+</td><td>' + data[i].ID + '</td><td>' + data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data[i].Address + '</td><td>' +  data[i].Phone + '</td><td>' +'</td></tr>');
                        $('#Mytable>tbody').append(row);
                        
                    }
                    $('#Mytable').show(); //show filter data


                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

my dropdownlist is use js to connection
filter data also
that's means after user selected city and area
data will be displayed

here is my html:

```
   <form>
    <div class="row well">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">City</span>
                <p>
                    @Html.DropDownList("City", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Allcity, "Please select", new { id = "CITY" })
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Area</span>
                <p> <select id="AREA" name="AREA"><option>Please select</option></select></p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <button type="button" onclick="SearchallData()" id="ButtonSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>search
            </button>

        </div>


    </div>

<table id="Mytable" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="display:none;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>

<tbody>
    //first page table will not show any data so is null
</tbody>
```

and my controller

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {


            var b = new GetCollection();
            var areasource = await b.GetInserchdata();
            ViewBag.AllCity = areasource.Select(s => s.City).Distinct().Select(item => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = item,
                Value = item
            });


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr))
            {
                con.Open();
                string q = "Select * from Shopmap";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(q, con);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            return View(dt);


        }

       //js for first selected dropdownlist
       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetSecondDDL(string cityName)
        {
            var CitySlectList = this.GetSelectList(await GetCity(), cityName);


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityName))
            {
                return Json(new EmptyResult());
            }
            var AreaSlectList = await this.GetArea(cityName);

            return Json(AreaSlectList);


        }
       //js for selected second dropdownlist then search data
       [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetShopmap(string cityName, string areaName)
        {
            var b = new GetCollection();
            List<Inserch> shop = b.GetDBdata();
            var a = shop.FindAll(x => x.Address.Contains(cityName));
            var Alldata = a.FindAll(x => x.Address.Contains(areaName)).AsEnumerable();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(areaName))
            {
                return Json(new EmptyResult());
            }
           
            return Json(Alldata);
        }
```

I think it will use js to do what I want

then maybe c# code will put in
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetShopmap(string cityName, string areaName)->this function

please tell me what to do

I desperately need.

thank's.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can simply achive that using `jQuery` `datatable`. So get the data from your controller, then bind it to table which would autometically set the pagination other additional options like `searching, sorting`.

Comment: Hello, was the issue resolved? Have you tired the solution provided? Please let me know if any further assistance required on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Pagination for Dropdownlist filter data in ASP.NET MVC

You can achieve that in following way:

**HTML**

```
<table id="userTable_info">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id </th>
            <th>Controller </th>
            <th>Page_name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tBody"> </tbody>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
@section scripts {

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#userTable_info').hide();
        //On Submit Method

        $("#Submit").click(function () {
           
            var ddlCategory = parseInt($("#ddlCategory").val());
            var ddlSubCategorie = parseInt($("#ddlSubCategorie").val());

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://localhost:5094/Member/GetShopmap',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { cityName: ddlCategory, areaName: ddlSubCategorie },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                        var tr = "<tr>";
                        tr += "<td>" + value.ulogo_id + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + value.controller + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + value.page_name + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" +  "<input type='button' id='" + value.id + "'  class='btn btn-warning' onclick='EditFunc(" + value.id + ")' value='Edit'>" + "  " + "<input type='button' id='" + value.id + "'  class='btn btn-danger' onclick='DeleteFunc(" + value.id + ")' value='Delete'>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";

                        $("#tBody").append(tr);
                    });
                    $("#userTable_info").DataTable();
                    $('#userTable_info').show();
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**  Based on your table defination please implement the neccessary chnages. It ill work as expected.